# near linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm considering a situation where vectors are nearly linearly dependent.

Suppose that $A$ is $2 \times 2$ matrix

$A= \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & a \\
a & 1
\end{array}
\right] $

If $a=1$, $A$ is of course singular and linearly dependent. But if $a=0$ and $a=0.999$, $A$ is non-singular for both cases. But, apparently $a=0.999$ is more close to being singular or linearly dependent than $a=0$. In this $2 \times 2$ case, the determinant can be used to measure the closeness to being singular or linearly dependent.

Now consider $3 \times 2$ matrices $B_1$ and $B_2$

$B_1 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right] $

$B_1 = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0.999 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1.001
\end{array}
\right] $

Mathematically, both $B_1$ and $B_2$ are linearly dependent. But, $B_2$ is more close to being linearly dependent than $B_1$.

My question is are there any ways to measure the closeness to being linearly dependent for such non-square matrix. In other words, how can I demonstrate that $B_2$ is close to being linearly dependent than $B_1$.

Answer (score 1):

A square matrix of rank $r$ has $r$ non-zero eigenvalues (may be multiple). So it is singular iff one of its eigenvalues is zero. The determinant (i.e. the product of all eigenvalues) is not a good quantitative measure for singularity. For example the matrix
$\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
10^{10} & 0 \\
0 & 10^{-10}
\end{array}
\right] $
has determinant $1$ but clearly (for me) is more singular than the identity matrix.
The smallest eigenvalue by magnitude is a better measure for that (possibly normalized by the largest eigenvalue).

The generalization for non-square matrices you are looking for are [singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). The smallest singular value is zero for singular matrices and close to zero for almost singular matrices. In your example matrices they are [0.915272](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SingularValueDecomposition%5B%7B%7B1,%200%7D,%20%7B1,%201%7D,%20%7B1,2%7D%7D%5D) and [0.001](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SingularValueDecomposition%5B%7B%7B1,+0.999%7D,+%7B1,+1%7D,+%7B1,1.001%7D%7D%5D), respectively.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely. For square matrices, just calculate the determinant: if the result is close to zero, then the columns of your matrix are close to be linearly dependent (though, strictly speaking, they are not exactly linearly dependent). For a non-square matrix $B$, the columns are nearly dependent if the determinant of $B^TB$ is nearly zero.

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea! Thank you very much!